# If statement with char array not working properly

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, minesweeper

So I created a void function which should give a value of 178 to a 2D array. Then I created an if statement which checks whether or not this array is NOT equal to 178 and if it's NOT equal then the counter (int variable stevec) increases by 1. Running the debugger I found out that this condition is always true, but it should not, because all values in array are equal to 178 at the beginning. Also I declared char matrix[10][10]={}; outside all functions at the very beginning.

```
   void set_matrix_to_default()
{
    for(int y=1; y<=9; y++)
    {
        for(int x=1; x<=9; x++)
        {
            matrix[x][y]=178;
        }
    }
}

void Check_Win()
{
    int stevec=0;
    for(int y=1; y<=9; y++)
    {
        for(int x=1; x<=9; x++)
        {
            if(matrix[x][y]!=178)
            {
                stevec++;

            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }
    if(stevec==9*9)
    {
        cout<<"Konec igre, zmagal si!";
        exit(0);
    }
    else {}
}
```

Comment: Why are you starting your loops from index 1?  Arrays in C++ start from index 0.

Answer (score 5):

By default, `char` is a signed type.  On typical systems where `char` is 8-bits, that means it cannot hold the value `178`.  When you try to do this comparison, `matrix[x][y]` is promoted to `int` and will be negative.

The most sensible option would be to change the `matrix` type to `unsigned char` (or similar such as `uint8_t`).  That would allow you to correctly compare other matrix values with one another.  But this assumes you are always dealing with positive values.

If the matrix *must* store negatives too, then I'm afraid your datatype is too small and cannot hold the value `178`.

Otherwise, the simplest option is to cast the type to unsigned before comparing:

```
if (static_cast<unsigned char>(matrix[x][y]) != 178)
```

Comment: The signedness of `char` is implementation-defined, although signed is quite common. For numeric values, choosing `signed char` or `unsigned char` is far better than using plain `char`.